# How to change the active buttons theme in the controllgroup in JQM?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to change the theme of a clicked button in `jQuery Mobile Controlgroup`. In API I found method `buttonMarkup` which changes theme but only until the cursor is on the button.

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/25ssy/

Answer (score 2):

Choose any of the below solutions.

First one, instead of using `button` tag, use `a` with `data-role=button`.

```html
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="d">On duty</a>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/25ssy/1/)**

```js
$('a').on('click', function () {
  $(this).buttonMarkup({
    theme: 'b'
  });
});
```

Second one, you need to apply new theme to the div wrapping the `button`, using `.closest('div')`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/25ssy/2/)**

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('div').buttonMarkup({
    theme: 'b'
  });
});
```